# Enable admin console of Google Apps

Tags: google-workspace

I want to login to my free Google Apps admin console. I goto [here](http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business/index25.html?utm_expid=65468332-15), click `Sign in` at the upper right corner, and select "Domain Management" in the menu and sign in. I expect to see the admin console, but what I get is Email. I believe this once worked. I have no way to admin my domain now.

When I go to [this page](https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/example.org/AdminHome), I get the following message:

> Google Apps Administrator Control Panel has not been enabled by the
>   administrator of the domain @example.com.

How can I enable this?

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Comment: @Rubén, no, I think I lost admin privileges of my account. I will no longer be able to manage my domain.

Comment: Oh, I finally reclaimed management of my domain. I forgot my admin address and thought it was the regular one I created with in the domain. Thank you @Rubén.

Comment: @Rubén, and I have received the resetting instructions in Spain, maybe sent by you.

Comment: @Rubén, could you please mask the domain name from your comment? I am receiving email for reseting my password when anyone clicks on the link.

Comment: The comment was deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Rubén for help.

I went to https://admin.google.com/example.org/ForgotAdminAccountInfo to reset my admin password. Google sent the link for resetting the password to my secondary address, and I noticed that the admin address is different from what I tried before (I forgot the admin address). After a password resetting, I can now finally access my admin console.

Answer (score 1):

Did you complete the process of installing Google Apps? If so, then the Control Panel has to be enabled..it's the first thing that gets turned on. If you didn't complete that process, then finish and you should be able to login. Otherwise, this FAQ might be helpful - http://support.google.com/a/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=ts.cs&ts=2403965&from=2403965&rd=1

Comment: Yes, the account is the only account I have for my domain. It used to be an admin, but I do not know how it becomes a regular user. I simply cannot admin my domain.